# How to get long path in Delphi instead of short path?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I compile the following code (COM object) in Delphi XE8 64-bit

```
function TUtility.GetDLLPath: WideString;
var
  Buffer: array [0 .. C_MAX_PATH_LEN] of char;
begin
  GetModuleFileName(hInstance, Buffer, Length(Buffer));
  Result := Buffer;
end;
```

and I get the following path string (calling in VBScript)

```
C:\PROGRA~2\XYZ\AAABBB~1\64\Tools.dll
```

How do I get the long path instead of the short path?

Comment: Use e.g. `GetLongPathName` to get the long file name. The reason why did you get a short path name is described in [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) reference. It says about the `lpFilename` parameter: *The string returned will use the same format that was specified when the module was loaded. Therefore, the path can be a long or short file name, and can use the prefix "\\?\".* So this is just how that function behaves and has little to do with Delphi.

Comment: not quite following you.. .could you rewrite the above example using GetLongPathName?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for the two functions that TLama refers to. I'm sure that once you read the documentation it will be obvious.

Comment: hello, please check my updates, it doesn't work on D2007.

Comment: You missed the calling convention. Add `stdcall;` before `external...`. And the name of the function is `GetLongPathNameA`, not `GetShortPathNameA`.

Comment: thanks... yes. you are right... and I also tried with the unicode version and it works as well!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, the Unicode version should work for you as long as you'll use `WideString`s (just for displaying Unicode strings you'd need to use Unicode controls, such as TNT ones; don't know their current repository, if they even officially exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `GetLongPathName`:

```
function LongPathName(const ShortPathName: string): string;
var
  Retval: DWORD;
  Buff: array [0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
begin
  Retval := GetLongPathName(PChar(ShortPathName), Buff, Length(Buff));
  Win32Check(Retval <> 0);
  Result := Buff;
end;
```

Comment: The function does not return string ... I think should add Result := Buff

Comment: it works on XE8, but doesn't work on D2007... it says GetLongPathName not declared (in windows.pas). and I declare it but the function doesn't work (return strange numbers) for both non-unicode and unicode versions

Comment: Copy the declaration from the source code. You'll need the ANSI one.